# Leak on the aluminum sliding door frame

Tags: leak, door-frame, window-frame

I have a leak on my aluminum sliding door. The water leaks on the top between the aluminum track and the wood frame. This only happens when the direction of the rain towards the door and there is a wind blowing or it rains for 2 days. Where could possibly the leak from? These door has a flashing. Did it went inside the flashing? If so can i just put a silicon inside the flashing?

I updated the question and added additional pictures. I was following your advice yesterday and since it is raining , water is on the wall. I noticed that in this door, there is a vertical distance between the flashing and to top of the door (head flange) and there is also wider horizontal distance.

I enlarge the picture of the damage caulk. B is a caulk (white silicon) is like cut off (Fig A). Fig C which I put circle is wet. I push a cotton buds in A and it is wet. It seems the water comes from C and go up from there like capillary action? The other side of the flashing also has a caulk and it is dry on the inside.

latest update. Added picture of the top of the flashing.
[image]
[image]
[image: Flashing top of door]
[image: House has a window on top.]
[image: Is there should be a vertical clearance (V in Picture)?]

[image: Aluminum door inside the house]

[image: Aluminum Sliding Door outside the house]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The leak could be from directly outside the point where you're seeing water coming inside.
- It could be from anywhere along the top of the door frame and coming out at the point you see it inside.
- It could be from a window above the sliding door, running down the wall and coming out here.
- It could be from the roof - anywhere from the ridge on down, running down the inside of the wall and coming out here.

Unfortunately, because water flows along horizontal surfaces and clings to vertical and angled surfaces, it could be just about anywhere and flow all over the place. It's going to take investigation on your part (or an experienced and trustworthy carpenter/handyman) to determine the source.

It's pretty likely that it's directly (or nearly directly) outside the leak point inside, but it's no guarantee. You're going to have to get up on a ladder and give the top of the door frame a thorough inspection. If you find a spot that looks likely, aim the hose at it or pour a pitcher of water on that spot and see if something appears inside. If so, you've found your spot, if not, keep looking.

Depending on what that flashing looks like at the top of the frame, you could just run a good bead of caulk across the top and hope for the best.

---

Based on this more recently added photograph, this looks to be more of an issue than caulk will fix. It appears that the window frame (green line) is pulling away from the wall (red line). **THAT** is the problem that needs to be addressed, and caulk *IS NOT* the solution for it.

[image: annotated version of OPs pic showing where window frame is pulling away from the wall]

Unless this is *just* a piece of trim, this honestly looks like if it's left alone long enough, the whole window could end up falling out of the wall.

You're going to need to get up there on a ladder and push on it. If the whole window frame moves, you're going to need to *screw* (or possibly nail, but screws will be easier and safer working on a ladder near glass as a rookie) the whole window back into the wall. You might want to look behind the frame and into the wall cavity before doing so to assess the level of water damage that already exists there - it's possible that water has ruined insulation or even started to rot out the wood framing of the wall itself.

Once you've assessed damage and determined that it's safe to just screw this back on the wall, you'll want to use some longer and fatter screws through the existing holes in the flange, or make new ones if there are nails/screws where the existing holes are. Once it's securely screwed back to the wall, *then* is when you'll want to caulk the window to seal it.

To be honest, this might be getting beyond your abilities as a DIYer at this point. There's nothing wrong with waiving the white flag and hiring a professional to fix it if it's beyond your abilities. This is a water leak, working on a ladder on a 2nd floor window, assessing damage, and determining a repair are *not* beginner tasks. It's OK.

Comment: If there is old caulk on the flashing, it is usually best to remove the old stuff before putting new caulking on.

Comment: @FreeMan. There is a window on top of the sliding door. How does water comes from there? is it like the top window is damage and the one leaking?

With regards to the roof, the gutter seems fine, the eaves is not wet I think by looking from it. What do you mean by inside of the wall? Is it like the water is already inside in the cavity?

Comment: I really don't know where to put the silicon/caulk in the top flashing.  

I was thinking of the inside the vertical and horizontal gap?

Comment: I can't see the top of your flashing, so it's hard to make a recommendation, either. I see the new pics, and it does look like the arrows point to areas where there could be water leaking.

Comment: When there's a water leak, the water will get inside the wall of the house, between the outer layer of white stucco you see on the outside and the inside layer (probably drywall if built in the last 50 years in the US). Once in there, it can run for a while before finding another weak spot to exit the wall. There could be a small nail hole in your roof near the ridge where the water is getting in, then it's running down inside the wall, where you can't see it, then finally coming out above this door. It could be leaking it at that gap noted in your new pic and coming out above the door.

Comment: I'll get a picture of the top of the flashing in the morning to rule out. So inside of the flashing should be dry as standard?

Comment: In general, you want caulk in/over any gaps in materials. Either between the flashing and the wall, 2 pieces of overlapping flashing, or flashing and the window frame. You'll want these to be nice and clean (remove old caulk then use a wet rag to wipe of the accumulated dust/dirt/bird poo/cruft of life), then apply a nice bead of caulk over any an all seams, ensuring you've got good adhesion at the sides of the bead and no/minimal divots for water to collect in.

Comment: I edited the top and added some pictures. I have some analysis on it. Does it make sense? I will do a re-caulk on that damage silicon base on your steps.

Comment: I've made some updates, @TheOne. Be sure to take a look. I don't think just caulk is the answer for this...

Comment: @FreeMan  I think ill hire an expert. Thank you for the initial analysis.